# On creating azure container instance getting error message "unrecognized arguments:"

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I tried creating azure container instance using tags by running below CLI command

```
az container create --resource-group sonarQubeSQC --name sonarqube --image sonarqube --ports 9000 --dns-name-label sqc.sonarqube --tags "Client=Internal" "Environment=Test" "Owner=SQC" --cpu 2 --memory 3.5
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried to create an **Azure Container** with tags, but I am also getting the same error as you.

> Note: The `--tags` parameter is not supported in Azure **Container  Instances** with the current version of the **Azure CLI**. Follow the [az container create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/container?view=azure-cli-latest#az-container-create) using CLI.

[image]

You can use below code to create an **Azure Container** with tags parameter.

The first command will create a container using specified image.

```
az container create --resource-group "rg-31"--name "myapp" --image "mcr.microsoft.com/azuredocs/aci-helloworld:latest"  --os-type Windows --ports 80 443 --dns-name-label "venkatcontainer" --cpu 1 --memory 1
```

**Output:**

[image]

The second command adds tags to your container instance by specifying the tag key-value pairs and the container instance ID using the `--ids` parameter.

```
az resource tag --tags Client=Internal Environment=Test --ids $(az container show -g "rg-31" --name "myapp" --query "id" --output tsv)
```

**output:**

[image]

After running the above command, the **Azure Container Instance** was created successfully with tags.

[image]